# ImageSourceConverter throws a NullReferenceException ... why?

Tags: c#, wpf, resources

I've been tearing my hair out over this issue for the last hour or so.

I have some code that goes like this:

```
videoTile.Icon = new ImageSourceConverter().ConvertFrom(coDrivr4.Properties.Resources.Music.GetHbitmap()) as ImageSource;
```

When I run my code, it says a NullReferenceException occurred. Neither 'Music' nor the return of GetHbitmap() are null.

I'm trying to get the image via the Properties because it's the only way I've figured out how to access the images in my Resources folder. I would just add them to the app.xaml file as a resource, but I'm not using an app.xaml file for a few reasons.

Am I attempting this wrong? All I need to do is get an ImageSource object of an image I have in my Resource directory. I can use them just fine in my XAML, but can't for the life of me do it in any code.

P.S.: I can't just add them as a resource to the XAML file because this is just a class and so there is no XAML file.

Comment: There must be some additional information in the full exception stack

Comment: You would think that but there is literally nothing.

This is what comes out of 'Copy exception detail to clipboard':

System.NullReferenceException was unhandled
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=PresentationCore
  StackTrace:
       at System.Windows.Media.ImageSourceConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, Object value)
       at System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.ConvertFrom(Object value)
       at coDrivr4.Conductor.PopulateDefaultApplicationTiles() in
       ...
  InnerException:

Comment: I should also point out that I'm running VS2010 & .NET 4.0. Not terribly sure if that makes a whole lot of difference, but hey, it's beta.

Comment: That's not nothing - that shows that the exception is occurring in ImageSourceConverter.ConvertFrom, which *strongly* suggests that either the resource isn't found, or the conversion is failing in some other way. In particular, it rules out possibilities of: 1) videoTile is null; 2) ConvertFrom is returning null; 3) ConvertFrom is returning a non-ImageSource.

Comment: Oh, and it also proves that coDrivr4.Properties.Resources.Music isn't null. In other words, it rules out *four* of the possible sources of error. I'd say that's a lot more information than "literally nothing".

Comment: I had pretty much assumed/tested that already, you'll have to excuse my assumptions :) So, essentially, something is causing ConvertFrom() to fail. I'm not sure what it could be unless it's a bug in the beta, but it seems like that would've been found by now. I don't think it's the image itself that's causing the problems. I'm out of ideas at this point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well you've got plenty of things which *could* be null in there. I suggest you separate them out:

```
Bitmap bitmap = coDrivr4.Properties.Resources.Music;
object source = new ImageSourceConverter().ConvertFrom(bitmap.GetHbitmap());
ImageSource imageSource = (ImageSource) source;
videoTile.Icon = imageSource;
```

Note the use of a cast rather than the `as` operator here. If `source` *isn't* an `ImageSource`, this will throw an `InvalidCastException` which will be much more descriptive than just ending up as a null reference.

EDIT: Okay, so now we know for sure that it's happening in `ConvertFrom`, I suggest the next step is to find out whether it's a bug in .NET 4.0 beta 1. Are you actually using any .NET 4.0 features? I suggest you try to extract *just that bit of code* into a separate project (you don't need to display an API, just convert the image. Try to run that code in .NET 3.5. If it fails in the same way, that's eliminated the beta-ness from the list of possible problems.

Comment: That's not it either. The same error throws on the 'object source =...' line.

Comment: Right - but the important thing is that we've establish that it's definitely in ConvertFrom. Admittedly we'd have seen that immediately from the stack trace...

Comment: So what's the next step? I'm out of ideas for testing what's going wrong at this point.

Comment: See my edit - try it under .NET 3.5. You might also want to try different resources, to see if that's particular file. If you can put it in a short but complete program, you could post the whole program here and the file, and we could try it ourselves.

Comment: Under .NET 3.5, the exception thrown is that ConvertFrom() can't convert from the IntPtr given by GetHbitmap() and it won't convert it from just the Bitmap object. Call me crazy, but I swear this has worked previously. I'm going to dig through some old code to see if I can find an instance of this working, that would have been the only reason I instinctively used GetHbitmap() in the first place.

Comment: I'm getting the exact same problem, while it worked with older versions. Funny thing is, in VS008 with .NET 3.5 this worked, in VS2010 it does not and I'm sure the target isn't 4.0

Comment: VS2012 .NET 4.5, four years later the problem is still there! Note that imageSourceConverter.CanConvertFrom(iconBitmap.GetHbitmap().GetType()); returns false, likewise for all the other types discussed here.

Comment: VS2013 .NET 4.6, seven years later the problem is still there.

Answer (score 11):

I hit exactly the same issue - I've got all my bitmaps in a nice, statically typed resource file and I just want to set an ImageSource with them.  So, since the ImageSourceConverter was throwing null reference exceptions, I changed tack and used this piece of code instead:

```
Bitmap bitmap = entityCol.EntityCollectionImage;
this.Image = System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(bitmap.GetHbitmap(), IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty, BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions()); // Image is an image source
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: This works flawlessly. The ConvertFrom method still throws a NullReferenceException, even if the object I pass is not null (I double-checked with the Visual Studio debugger).

Comment: Works very well inside my ValueConverter. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

This is not a bug in .net Framework, this null reference exception occurs because the ImageSourceConverter cannot convert a Bitmap type object, it can to convert: Stream, string, Uri, byte[], so you have to change your code to something like this:

```
var imageSourceConverter = new ImageSourceConverter();
byte[] tempBitmap = BitmapToByte(eventArgs.Frame);
ImageSource image = (ImageSource)imageSourceConverter.ConvertFrom(tempBitmap);
```

...

```
private byte[] BitmapToByte(Bitmap bitmap)
{
    byte[] byteArray;
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        bitmap.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
        stream.Close();

        byteArray = stream.ToArray();
    }
    return byteArray;
}
```

Comment: I encounter a really strange Overflow error when calling `GetHbitmap` . So I change to your method, it works great! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Before use ConvertFrom save your bitmap to MemoryStream

```
Bitmap canvas = new Bitmap(secScreen.Bounds.Width, secScreen.Bounds.Height);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(canvas);
g.Clear(System.Drawing.Color.Yellow);

MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream ();
canvas.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
ImageSource isrg = (ImageSource)new ImageSourceConverter().ConvertFrom(stream);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the return value of `coDrivr4.Properties.Resources.Music.GetHbitmap()` into a temp variable and see if it's null -- that may be where your null is coming from.

Comment: It's definitely not null, according to both the debugger and my quick in-code test.