# How to create DependencyProperty from two different properties

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

I have `UserControl` with property which looks like this:

```
public string Text
{
    get
    {
        return string.Format("{0}:{1}", Text1, Text2);
    }
    set
    {
        var array = value.Split(':');
        Text1 = array[0];
        Text2 = array[1];
    }
}
```

Note that `Text1` and `Text2` are texts from two `TextBox` controls. Now I need to convert this property to `DependencyProperty` but [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613563.aspx#implications) says that I should avoid any logic in get and set definitions so where I can put my logic for get and set or how I can do this differently?

**EDIT**
So I have here three similar answers but `Value Changed Callback` solves only code from `set` and not from `get`. This code works only if I set property from code but not when I change `Text1` or `Text2`.

**EDIT 2**
I want to use this new `DependencyProperty` as target of `TwoWay` binding.

Comment: You may consider to create an ordinary dependency property of type string and then use a MultiBinding with a multi-value converter to bind it to the two TextBoxes.

Comment: @Clemens I don't understand how I can use MultiBinding here. I want to use this value from another `UserControl` and possibly also from code. Can you please post some code snippet?

Comment: You would have to explain what `Text1` and `Text2` exactly are. Are they other dependency properties in your UserControl, or should they just be the `Text` properties of two TextBox members of your control?

Comment: Now they are only `Text` properties of two `TextBox` members: `textBox1.Text` and `textBox2.Text`.

Answer (score 2):

You can try creating a Dependency Property and in the PropertyChangedCallBack you can perform your split logic. Let me know if this fixes your problem

```
 public string Text
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(MyClass), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty,valueChanged));
        private static void valueChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            MyClass c = d as MyClass;
            if(c!=null)
            {
                var array = e.NewValue.ToString().Split(':');
                c.Text1 = array[0];
                c.Text2 = array[1];
            }
        }
```

Comment: Where could I learn more about dependency properties? Can you on MSN? A link would be nice.

Answer (score 2):

In WPF, for a `DependencyProperty`, the Setters and Getters for properties will rarely be called (WPF usually uses the `SetValue` and `GetValue` methods of `DependencyObject`).

In order to "do" anything when the value changes you can provide a `PropertyChangedCallback` in the `FrameworkMetadata` for the `DependencyProperty`:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "Text", typeof (string), typeof (ColorPicker), new PropertyMetadata(default(string), OnTextChanged));

private static void OnTextChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var control = d as UserControl;
    if (null == control) return; // This should not be possible

    var newValue = e.NewValue as string;
    if (null == newValue) return;

    var split = newValue.Split(':');
    control.Text1 = split.ElementAtOrDefault(0);
    control.Text2 = split.ElementAtOrDefault(1);
}

public string Text
{
    get { return (string) GetValue(TextProperty); }
    set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
}
```

Note that the "OnTextChanged" method is static and that you have to 'manually' convert the DependencyObject to your control's type. (Substitute `var control = d as UserControl` with your control type).

Comment: You should replace `d as UserControl` by `(UserControl)d`, because that would correctly throw an InvalidCastException in case the property changed callback would inadvertently be used with the wrong object type.

Comment: Just do your error handling in `if (null == control) { ... }` I think it's much nicer to not have .Net throw an `InvalidCastOperation` if you can handle it before it occurs.

Comment: See what [Jon Skeet has to say about that topic](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1036482/1136211). Couldn't quickly find more examples, but common sense is that your code *should* throw an InvalidCastException if you cast to something you don't expect.

Comment: If the purpose is to be more descriptive, then throw a 'proper' exception in the `if (null == control)` block. I do believe this is more a question of taste than anything else really, the scenario you linked to does not 'handle' the case of `ImageSource` being `null`, in which case a `NullReferenceException` would be thrown, this is not the case in my example.
But again, this is mostly a question of taste I guess.

Comment: I don't want to start a lengthy discussion about this, but which exception would be more "proper" than InvalidCastException? Seriously, you've written your property changed callback for exactly one DependencyObject-derived class. Any other type is just an error, and currently your code just ignores this. It is much cleaner and safer to use an explicit cast here, that is no matter of taste.

Comment: What I don't like about the explicit cast is that it 'looks' like the code being executed is flawed, in that it doesn't handle an invalid type on its own. If an InvalidCastException is necessary, then 'show' the reader that this is supposed to happen with `throw new InvalidCastException("This property is only valid for the UserControl type");` although personally I'd probably go with an `InvalidOperationException`.

Answer (score 1):

Your entire User Control will be like this:

```
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    public MyUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(MyUserControl), 
        new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnTextChanged)));

    private static void OnTextChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var myControl = d as MyUserControl;
        if (null != myControl)
        {
           var newValue = e.NewValue as string;
           if (null != newValue)
           {
                var split = newValue.Split(':');
                myControl.Text1 = split[0];
                myControl.Text2 = split[1];
           }
        }
    }

    public string Text1 { get; set; }
    public string Text2 { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a normal dependency property and assign a MultiBinding that binds to the Text properties of your two TextBoxes.

First, the dependency property declaration:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "Text", typeof(string), typeof(UserControl1));

public string Text
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
    set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
}
```

Now you have to create a converter class to be used with your MultiBinding. The converter performs the string split and join logic (btw for an arbitray number of substrings):

```
class TextConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(
        object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return string.Join(":", values);
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(
        object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return ((string)value).Split(':');
    }
}
```

Finally, create and apply a MultiBinding to the `Text` property in the UserControl's constructor:

```
public UserControl1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var binding = new MultiBinding
    {
        Converter = new TextConverter(),
        Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay
    };

    binding.Bindings.Add(new Binding
    {
        Source = textBox1,
        Path = new PropertyPath("Text"),
        Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay
    });

    binding.Bindings.Add(new Binding
    {
        Source = textBox2,
        Path = new PropertyPath("Text"),
        Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay
    });

    SetBinding(TextProperty, binding);
}
```

The drawback of this solution is that any other binding to the `Text` property (e.g. somewhere else in your code, where you use your control) would replace the MultiBinding. You can however always use the `Text` property as source property in a two-way binding to a property of another element.

Comment: Thanks but I don't like that drawback. I want to use `Text` property with binding. That was the main reason why I want to switch to `DependencyProperty`. I should mention that in my question. Sorry.

Comment: As said, you might still use `Text` as the source property of a two-way or one-way-to-source binding.

Comment: Well I want to use `TwoWay` binding but I need `Text` as target not as source.